# How to search User in LDAP to build Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL in java

Tags: java, authentication, active-directory, ldap

I have a requirement in LDAP as below to build in Java.

1. Connect to the directory server using the generic principal
2. Search for the user.
3. Obtain the user’s distinguished name
4. Reconnect using the distinguished name(multiple DN for one user) and the user’s password to validate the user’s credentials.

The user will falls under different groups , so i need to verify first user exists in LDAP or not and then i need to authenticate the user and password.

Can anyone help me to build the requirement in Java.

Comment: What did you try ? What is failing ?

Comment: I need a piece of code in java how to search for a user before authenticating

Comment: You need to create an InitialDirectoryContext with your  generic principal and then do a context search for a user. You can find plenty of samples on internet on googling.

Comment: Or even SOF itself . See the comments on this post.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39224955/getting-user-dn-with-user-name-ldap

Comment: I need to retrieve the User group based on the username before authenticating how can i do that ?